# How to save workbook as a template

Tags: excel, vba, office365

I'm creating a spreadsheet to be used as a data entry form. It has a tab with a bunch of configuration information that the master user can edit. My idea is that after making any changes I would like to save it as a template via a macro so that new workbooks can be created for users simply.

I've found that

```
file_name = Environ("localappdata") & "\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\"
```

will return the correct path for templates however I get an exception whenever I try to save a file to that path.

```
file_name = Environ("localappdata") & "\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\MasterIntakeForm"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=file_name, _
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLTemplateMacroEnabled, _
    AccessMode:=xlExclusive, _
    ConflictResolution:=Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges
```

[image: Excel error dialog]

You can see that the filename has been mangled for some reason. The file doesn't currently exist in that location so the conflict resolution part isn't the problem. Removing everything after the fileformat doesn't change anything.

Comment: You're missing a file extension at the end of your `file_name`. I think the template extension is `.xltx`. I can see that you're trying to use `FileFormat`, but maybe try adding the extension anyways.

Comment: Check your path, is it `local` or `roaming` that you want?  `Appdata\Local\Roaming` doesn't exist.

Comment: Good pick @Profex, make that an answer please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path is invalid, use the following, which included the `Roaming` folder:

```
file_name = Environ("appdata") & "\Microsoft\Templates\MasterIntakeForm"
```